# use jquery to increases variable value by 1 when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, button, click

I'm trying to make a button that will increase a variable by one each time the button is clicked using jQuery.

This is the jQuery and HTML code to create the button I've used.

```
$('.runHome').on('click', myfunction);
function myfunction() {
    $(this).number(++runHome);
<div class="runHome">0</div>
<button>RunsHome</button>
```

The variable is `runHome` and it is also a class.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first attach click on button then calculate the current value and set the increment.

Please refer this code

```
var numVal = parseInt($(".runHome").text());    

$('button').click(function(){
  ++numVal;
  $(".runHome").text(numVal);
});
```

and also refer this working link : -http://jsbin.com/juhixeruqe/2/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1):

You have added click handler to div instead of button, so button click won't work here:

```
$('.runHome').on('click', myfunction);
```

Try below changes:

```js
$(function() {
  var homeRuns = 0;
  var runHome = $('.runHome').text(homeRuns); //default text
  $('#homeBtn').on('click', function() {
    runHome.text(++homeRuns);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="runHome"></div>
<button id='homeBtn'>Runs Home</button>
```